# HSTS understanding

Tags: security, ssl, https, tls1.2, hsts

I'm interested in HSTS mechanism and want to clarify following moment:

For example, there is site https://example.com exists. I use [chrome://net-internals/#hsts](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts) to check if HSTS enabled there. And it shows the next information:

```
static_sts_domain: 
static_upgrade_mode: UNKNOWN
static_sts_include_subdomains: 
static_sts_observed: 
static_pkp_domain: 
static_pkp_include_subdomains: 
static_pkp_observed: 
static_spki_hashes: 
dynamic_sts_domain: example.com
dynamic_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS
dynamic_sts_include_subdomains: true
dynamic_sts_observed: 1524145911.957196
dynamic_sts_expiry: 1555681911.957194
dynamic_pkp_domain: 
dynamic_pkp_include_subdomains: 
dynamic_pkp_observed: 
dynamic_pkp_expiry: 
dynamic_spki_hashes:
```

So I expect and think that HSTS is enabled there. But at the same moment there is no `Strict-Transport-Security` header in response. Why does chrome show such information and is HSTS enabled for that site?

Comment: There exists an HSTS preloading list that lists domains/TLD used by browsers for which HSTS apply even before the first request. See hstspreload.org

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - those are listed in the static portion and ask you can see from the question those are blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But at the same moment there is no Strict-Transport-Security header in response.

It must have been there at some point because the dynamic entry has been added to your instance of Chrome.

Also remember that HSTS can be sent on any resource, not just the main document. So if you have it being sent on a logo resource, then that will set it for the whole domain.

You could clear it using the same `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` page and see if it comes back after browsing around? If so then something is still sending it, if not then maybe the site used to advertise HSTS but no longer does.

It was set to be active for one year:

```
(1555681911.957194 - 1524145911.957196) / 365 / 24 / 60 = 1 year
```

And from my rough calculations trying to convert those date stamps, it looks like it was last set on 20th April 2018.

If the site has indeed stopped using HSTS, for whatever reason, it might be better to advertise a 0 header instead so at least those visitors that visit over HTTPS now will remove the policy:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
```

Anyone who doesn't visit over HTTPS will not get this cleared until it expires.

Comment: This behavior dissapeared after deletion HSTS policies via `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`. I figured out this after reading about Chrome:
`But be aware that Chrome also likes to added entries whenever you request a site over https.`

Comment: No it doesn't it only adds if: 1) Your site advertises it as such, or it's 2) preloaded. Note that some top level domains (e.g. .dev) are preloaded so every site on them will be forced into HSTS: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: It is listed just a bit differently on the military side:  8 minutes is suggested.   https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/microsoft_iis_10.0_server/2020-06-08/finding/V-100189    (Obviously Windows... there is another STIG for Linux folks)

Answer (score 0):

HSTS represents HTTP Strict Transport Security. At the point when you have HSTS support it doesn't permit the site to be initially stacked in HTTP before utilizing the 301 redirects. This implies there is no time for any programmers to slip in and use it with HTTP and keep the site from stacking HTTPS. HSTS permits the site to stack just in HTTPS giving an additional layer of security for your site. This security layer tells the program that the site has HTTPS assurance and there is no compelling reason to attempt to access the site in HTTP. This will close the little window that the programmers got during the 301 redirects.
See Steps below:

[image]

To know detailed understanding of hypertext protocols and HSTS support [**click here**](https://www.bthrust.com/difference-between-http-https-and-hsts-support-and-their-affect-on-seo.html).